# Kubernetes: Define environment variables dependent on other ones using "envFrom"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment

I have two `ConfigMap` files. One is supposed to be "secret" values and the other has regular values and should import the secrets.

Here's the sample secret `ConfigMap`:

```yaml
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: secret-cm
data:
  MY_SEKRET: 'SEKRET'
```

And the regular `ConfigMap` file:

```yaml
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: regular-cm
data:
  SOME_CONFIG: 123
  USING_SEKRET: $(MY_SEKRET)
```

And my deployment is as follows:

```yaml
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my_container
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: secret-cm
            - configMapRef:
                name: regular-cm
```

I was hoping that my variable `USING_SEKRET` would be `"SEKRET"` because of the order the `envFrom` files are imported but they just appear as `"$(MY_SEKRET)"` on the Pods.

I've also tried setting the dependent variable as an `env` directly at the Deployment but it results on the same problem:

```yaml
kind: Deployment
...
  env:
    - name: MY_SEKRET
      # Not the expected result because the variable is openly visible but should be hidden
      value: 'SEKRET'
```

I was trying to follow the documentation guides, based on the [Define an environment dependent variable for a container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-interdependent-environment-variables/#define-an-environment-dependent-variable-for-a-container) but I haven't seen examples similar to what I want to do.

Is there a way to do this?

EDIT:
To explain my idea behind this structure, `secret-cm` whole file will be encrypted at the repository so not all peers will be able to see its contents.
On the other hand, I still want to be able to show everyone where its variables are used, hence the dependency on `regular-cm`.
With that, authorized peers can run `kubectl` commands and variable replacements of `secret-cm` would work properly but for everyone else the file is hidden.

Comment: As you observed, the `$()` resolution only happens in `PodSpec`'s `env:` blocks, and it is only one level of indirection (so no such thing as `$($(USING_SEKRET))` which is what you are apparently trying to do); what outcome are you trying to achieve with that double indirection? If you want all Deployments to share a common `DATABASE_URL` definition, why not just do that?

Comment: @mdaniel Sorry about the typo on the last example, but from my edit I wanted to explain that the `secret-cm` file would not be available for everyone, that's why I wanted to be able to "import" it on the regular file.

Comment: Fun fact: SEKRET is a word (in Polish;)

Answer (score 1):

You did not explain why you want to define two configmap (one getting value from another) but I am assuming that you want the env parameter name define in confgimap be independent of paramter name used by your container in pod. If that is the case then create your configmap
`kind: ConfigMap metadata: name: secret-cm data: MY_SEKRET: 'SEKRET'`

Then in your deployment use the env variable from configmap

```
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my_container
          env:
            - name: USING_SEKRET
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: secret-cm
                  key: MY_SEKRET
```

Now when you access env variable $USING_SEKRET, it will show value as 'SEKRET'

incase your requirement is different then ignore this response and provide more details.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This is what I currently have and works, but ultimately I wanted to be able to "import" all the variables from a single file instead of copying each one...

Comment: That is not supported - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/77632